# Blacklist.conf "Ignoring Bad Line Boot Prompt"

Tags: boot, kernel

[image: boot prompt]

Alright Ubuntu wizards, I jacked up my system a bit unnecessarily, which is now giving me the chance to learn more about how to fix it...a vicious cycle. Anyway, I have it mostly up and running again to my liking, though I am receiving this (photo attached) prompt when my system boots:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf line 56: ignoring bad line starting with 'rt2800usb'
```

Other users had success with just deleting the bad line from their blacklist.conf file, which I have done. Line 56 no longer exists, but I'm still receiving the same error. So am I missing something? Is there some follow-up command I need to give Ubuntu after saving the conf file?

Comment: Mine still shows up... No idea how to get rid of it. Bout ready to reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it fixed itself...or it's because I deleted that bad line. It's probably because I deleted the bad line.

Here is how I accessed the blacklist file:

1. Open the terminal
2. Type the command `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to open the `blacklist.conf` file
3. Locate the bad line, delete it, and save the file

In my case, I stopped receiving the error after a few restarts. Don't know why it delayed.

Answer (score 2):

The copy of `blacklist.conf` consulted during boot, to produce that `ignoring bad line` error, is the one in the [initial RAM filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs).

(That copy's fully qualified path is `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, like the one you edited. But at the point during boot when it is consulted, `/` is the initial RAM filesystem rather than your regular root filesystem stored on disk.)

This explains why the problem was not fixed immediately when you edited the `blacklist.conf` stored in your regular root filesystem.

The initial RAM filesystem is (re)built under some circumstances, such as when a new kernel is installed and as a result of some driver installations and some configuration changes. I think such an event probably triggered your delayed fix.

For the benefit of others, and in case you have this problem again, you can run

```
update-initramfs -k all -c
```

to rebuild (`-c`) the initial RAM filesystem for all installed kernels (`-k all`). Each installed kernel has its own associated initramfs.

Credit for this solution goes to [Christian](https://askubuntu.com/users/160876/christian), who [presented it as part of an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/527080/22949) to [Ubuntu update caused system to freeze on boot at purple screen. Recovery mode fails and brings up BusyBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504593/ubuntu-update-caused-system-to-freeze-on-boot-at-purple-screen-recovery-mode-fa), which is a more complicated version of this problem. In that question, the bad `blacklist.conf` (or other factors) actually prevented the system from booting successfully, and it was necessary for the fix to be applied [in a chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). That was fortunately not necessary in this case.

Since your problem went away by itself (here and [there, too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530465/libkmod-eror-ignoring-bad-line-start-up-issue)), I tested that solution to make sure it works. On an Ubuntu Server 14.10 Beta 2 system (as that's what I had handy for testing), I deliberately produced the problem by creating a bad line in my `blacklist.conf` file and running `update-initramfs -k all -c`. (As expected, just editing the file didn't produce the error on reboot--I had to rebuild the initial RAM filesystem to apply the changes.) Reverting to the original, correct `blacklist.conf` file did not immediately correct the problem, but did once I ran `update-initramfs -k all -c` again, as expected.

<sub>As a secondary matter, when editing `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` or other files that have to be edited [as root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), if you wish to use Gedit, I recommend running it as `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, as running graphical programs as root with straight `sudo` [sometimes creates root-owned configuration files in your home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application), interfering with the application's functioning when you run it normally later. If the [gksu [image: Install gksu]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gksu) package (which provides `gksudo`) isn't installed, you can use `sudo -H` or `sudo -i` instead.</sub>