# "Libkmod: EROR... ignoring bad line" start-up issue

Tags: boot

Just started using Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and when i try to boot it, it gives me this error message. After error message it boots successfully.

The point is, i had this "ath9k.conf" file in directory but i deleted it. Thought that its going to stop giving this error (beginner, sorry), but its not. The error is still here.

I created this ath9k.conf file few days ago because my notebook have a wifi button problem so i found solution to create it and add few lines in it. It didn't help and i forgot to delete it. I successfully fixed that problem by binding my WiFi toggle to another key (instead of Fn+F2, just on F2) because almost every Asus notebook has that problem.

What should i do? That error is just annoying.

[image]

If you need more information, let me know.

I'm running Asus X552V.

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the bad `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` file? according to the error message it still exists.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, i'm sure. I used command `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf`

Answer (score 0):

It magically stopped showing error when the Linux start-up after i deleted file and restarted a few times. I don't know the reason why it required few restarts.